# Specify or modify class library style resource values from referencing add-ins

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a c# wpf-based class library with models, view models, and views, which I am using in multiple add-ins for dektop applications that have APIs which support hosted dockable WPF user controls. From here I can use different controls and launch dialogs to interact with various data structures in the 3rd-party application. My class library doesn't have an App.xaml file.

I have created a ResourceDictionary xaml file that I am using as a main style sheet throughout my views. In my user controls and windows, I reference it:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/styleMain.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries
```

Inside of this style sheet, I manage my various controls to simplify and unify my views. At the lowest level, I have settings for things like font size, font family, and color. For example, I have several brushes that I use throughout my controls. One looks like this:

```
<Color x:Key="ColorBase_Primary" R="255" G="0" B="115" A="255"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Color_Primary" Color="{StaticResource ColorBase_Primary}"/>
```

This all works great for design and testing. However, I am referencing this class library in multiple other projects. In these other projects, I am hosting the main user control from my class library:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyAppHost.ucDockingHost"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyAppHost"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyClassLibrary.ViewModels;assembly=MyClassLibrary"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyClassLibrary.Views;assembly=MyClassLibrary"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModels:vmMain/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <views:ucMainGrid ViewModelMain="{Binding}" Property1="SomeValue" Property2="SomeOtherValue"/>
    </Grid>  
</UserControl>
```

Here I am setting DependencyProperties from the add-in application that references my class library without any problems, and all of my bindings and control behaviors are working great.

What I am now hoping to do is be able to specify from my add-in (and not the main class library) the basic resource values that are used throughout my style sheet, especially color (as in being able to change the value associated with `x:Key="ColorBase_Primary"`). This way, I can adapt different implementations to the branding of different clients, etc. I have been searching for a long time for any examples or insight and keep coming up short.

It would be easy enough to simply deploy the entire class library independently with each application and adjust the style sheet directly, but that doesn't seem right at all. Is there some way for me to create a ResourceDictionary in my add-in applications that could supply, modify or and/override the resource values specified in my class library? Or should I do it through a DependencyProperty in my view model? That doesn't seem right either.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. Do you want to override some resources that are defined in the referenced class library in a specific application or what is your issue?

Comment: You do understand my question. I'd like to reference my class library other applications, and in those applications be able to override some resources.

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* use the `MergedDictionaries` in your library, i.e. remove this:

In your application, you then merge all resource dictionaries from your library in the correct order:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfControlLibrary1;component/Brushes.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfControlLibrary1;component/Controls.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brush">Red</SolidColorBrush>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

You can then simply override any resource you want by defining another resource with the same `x:Key` like I have done with the `SolidColorBrush` above. This resource overrides any resource with an `x:Key` of "brush" defined in either `Brushes.xaml` or `Controls.xaml`.

Comment: Because I am building add-ins for 3rd party software that allow me to host WPF controls, neither my class library nor assembly that references it has an application xaml file in which I could follow that pattern.

Comment: The assembly gets loaded into an Application that has a Resources property at some Point. Merge the dictionaries then. Or what exactly is your question?